# Creating multiple Django model forms to change/edit multiple existing objects on the same page without passing object-id via URL

Tags: django, view, instance, modelform

I'm trying to build an Object detection service where the user can choose multiple objects he would like to detect. The Object Model looks like the following:

```
#models.py

class Object(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
image = models.ImageField()
detect = models.BooleanField(default=False)

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('Objectdetector:objectdetail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

The page is showing an overview of all the objects a user has created and there is a checkbox next to each object linked to the "detect" attribute. The model form looks like this:

```
#forms.py

class DetectForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Object
    fields = ['detect']
```

So in the views.py I'm trying to stick to the Django documentation and pass the instance to the form like such:

```
 form = DetectForm(instance = objectinstance)
```

but i can't figure out how I am supposed to do it correctly. This is the view, you can ignore the post method for now:

```
class DetectView(generic.ListView):

template_name = 'Objectdetector/detect.html'

def get(self,request):

    objectinstance = #Please help
    form = DetectForm(instance = objectinstance)
    objs = Object.objects.all()
    args = {'form':form, 'all_obj': objs}
    return render(request, self.template_name, args)

def post(self, request):


    form = DetectForm(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('Objectdetector:detectobjects')
    args = {'form':form}
    return render(request, self.template_name, args)
```

I then want to loop through all objects and display the images and names linked to them (already working) and display the checkbox next to each object. When the user checks the box of an object and hits submit, the detect attribute should be updated to true. Unfortunately I can only loop through the objects and display a checkbox, but when I hit submit, a new object is created. The table in the detect.html file looks like this:

```
#detect.html
<table class="table">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Image</th>
                        <th>Select</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    {% for object in all_obj %}
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                {{ object.name }}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <img src="{{ object.image.url }}" height="100">
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <form method = "post" >
                                    {% csrf_token %}
                                    {{ object.id }}
                                    {{form.as_p}}
                                <button type="submit">CONTINUE</button>
                                </form>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                    </tbody>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

Everything else is working fine, I just don't know how to create and show the checkboxes with the right instance.
I'm pretty sure that I'm missing something very small here due to my lack of Django-knowledge. I would be so happy if someone could help me out!

Thank You so much.

Comment: A model form is for a single instance, and accepts that instance as a parameter. But your ListView has *multiple* instances, so it doesn't make sense to try and instantiate a single form there. You could use a model formset.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Thanks, that was exactly what i was looking for !